# Angular/Firefox: Missing Text arround a Path if URL-parameters in place

Tags: angular, svg, firefox

I have a problems with Text on a SVG-path in combination with Firefox.
Think it is a bug.

Using Firefox 78.15, Angular 13.0.2, Debian 10.11 and Kernel 4.19.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
 Version={{ver.full}}
 <hr/>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="300" width="300">
        <path id="p1" fill="transparent" stroke="blue" d="M 100 100 A 100 100 0 0 0 200 200" stroke="blue"/>
        <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="green" text-anchor="middle">
            <textPath startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#p1">Hello there!</textPath>
        </text>
    </svg>

  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  ver = VERSION;
}
```

It is about the text "Hello there!" arround the path.

- Chromium (90.0.x) => OK
- Firefox with simple localhost:4200 => OK
- Firefox with a URL-parameter (e.g. localhost:4200?x=3) => **Text is missing!**

Why is that? How can I get my path in FF with a URL-parameter?

Comment: Firefox 78 is very old, update to the current version.

Comment: Yes, FF 94 does not have the problem.